# Why does PHP just work with Ajax but Python doesn't?

Tags: php, python, ajax

Building a PHP script that responds to an Ajax request is as easy as:

```
<?php
  $command = $_POST["command"];
  if ($command == "say_hello") {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Hello, " . $name));
  }
?>
```

and, at least if you're using jQuery on the client side, and if you specified a callback function on the original request, the array containing the message will be passed into that callback function.

But with Python it's not that simple. Or at least I haven't figured out how to make it that simple.  If I just try to "print" a response (paralleling PHP's "echo" statement above) the client doesn't get anything back.

Whenever I've looked on the internet for how to respond to an Ajax request with Python, the answer always involves using Django or some other web framework.

And I know those things are great, but what is PHP doing that makes using a similar package unnecessary?  I would like to be writing my server-side script in Python instead of PHP, but I'd prefer a D.I.Y. approach to using a third-party framework for what should be (right?) a pretty simple task.

Any help?  An example of how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to set up your server to serve data from Python programs. Could be through CGI, mod_python, or using WSGI (Python Server Gateway Interface). Python's standard library comes with the [cgi module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html), which is a basic way to interact with web servers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But with Python it's not that simple. Or at least I haven't figured out how to make it that simple. If I just try to "print" a response (paralleling PHP's "echo" statement above) the client doesn't get anything back.

I might have some of the details wrong, but I'll try to explain why this is the case. Firstly, the PHP you're talking about is baked directly into the apache webserver. When you do an `echo`, it outputs the result to the response stream (a TCP connection between the server and client). When you do `print` in python, what you're doing is outputting the result to standard out (the command line).

How most languages work with the web, is that a request comes in to some kind of web server, and that web server executes a program. The program is responsible for returning a stream, which the webserver takes, and streams to the client over the TCP connection.

I'm assuming that the webserver redirects PHPs standard out to the webservers stream, and that is how PHP is able to use `echo` to return its result. This is the exception, not the rule.

So, to use python to serve requests, you need to have a webserver that can execute python in some way. This is traditionally done using CGI. More recently, something like `mod_python` was used to host the python within apache. Nowadays, `wsgi` or `mod_wsgi` is used, which is the standard defined for webservers talking to python.

You might want to look at something like [web.py](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial), which is a minimalist python web framework. This will get you very very close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: beat me to a similar explanation! :-P now i feel like i have a duplicate answer

Comment: @ravenac95 hah very close. Difference being I suggested web.py rather than flask. Good to know I was on the right track :P

Answer (score 4):

PHP was built with the web in mind from the very beginning. In contrast Python was designed as a general purpose language.

When you echo from PHP you're actually writing to a stream that is sent to the user as part of an HTTP response. When you do a print in python the output, by default, is written to the stdout stream which means instead of being sent to the user over http the output is written to the console (or whatever is capturing stdout at the moment).

So to PHP, HTTP is a first class citizen. To more general purpose languages like Python, Ruby, Erlang, C, C++, and so many other languages. You have to communicate to HTTP in different ways. PHP already handles that communication through apache's mod_php or through something like PHP-FPM.

Sooo....

As far as creating your own server side script, I'd highly suggest against it as Python's Frameworks take the place of the layer that PHP is built on. So creating a standards compliant http server on your own with Python isn't going to be very simple. The reason that this is so hard is that you'd either have to interface with CGI or WSGI (a Python standard for dealing with the web) or create your own HTTP server. If you think you're up to the task then I highly suggest it! You'd probably learn a whole lot by doing it, but it isn't going to be the easiest thing. The great thing is that so many libraries already take care of this communication for you. For example, if you're looking for something lightweight, I highly suggest a micro-framework like [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) which is one I personally use if I need something very simple. It is much easier to get started than django, but it also has less batteries included.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There is a python module called [json](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/json/). Perhaps so many of the answers deal with frameworks (like Django) because json is web-centric and Django, tornado, twisted, cherrypy, etc. all are the means by which python interacts with the web.

There are many different ways to do this, and those are addressed in other questions. However, to just answer your question, python has a [json library in its standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Answer (score 0):

Most PHP installers configure themselves by default to serve php files in web directories by running the script.  Most Python installers do not.  Quickest way to serve Python with apache:

- In your apache config file, add `AddHandler cgi-script .py` to whatever  block can already serve PHP files
- shebang your python scripts by adding #!/usr/local/bin/python or whatever path python is on in your system
- remember to print headers first, followed by a newline, then body.
- use `import cgi` if you want to do anything more complicated than sending back a response body.

Note that this is not the *recommended* way to run a python website, just the *fast, php-ish way*.

Answer (score 0):

Richardhsu has the gist of it correct.

Essentially python is a general purpose scripting language.  As such, it needs a way to connect to the web, such as by opening a port and doing network programming etc.  You can also use something CGI to attach to apache or other web server.

This is really no different then how Java, Ruby, Perl or C/C++ get to the web either.  In fact, PHP does much the same thing.  It's interface to the web server is just tighter then CGI.

If you were to have PHP interpreted from the command line, or compiled, then you would have the exact same issues that you do with Python now. The issue isn't PHP vs Python, it's how you get the scripting language of your choice attached to the internet using the HTTP protocol.